# Is RAA just MT?

Tags: logic

If I say P and it leads to ~ Q then I have a false conditional . So imagine I want to prove ~ P then I show that Q is false as in

If P then Q

~ Q

~ P

We can do it the other way too

If ~ P then Q

~ Q

P

Comment: You can see [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) for clarifications.

Comment: I was asking is RAA  dependent on MT or is it the other way around . I know what contraposition is and that it is used in MT

Answer (score 0):

**Modus tollens** is the rule that : from P => Q and ~Q you may infer ~P.

This does not require *reduction to absurdity* to prove.  It is constructively valid.

```
|  P => Q
|_ ~Q
|  |_ P
|  |  Q     MP 1,3
|  |  #     ~E 2,4 
|  ~P       ~I 3-5
```

There is a *similar* rule that : from ~P => ~Q and Q you may infer P.

This is not constructively valid.  It is also, *not* modus tollens, although it is often used as if it were in less-strict classical proofs.

```
|  ~P => ~Q
|_ Q
|  |_ ~P
|  |  ~Q    MP 1,3
|  |  #     ~E 2,4
|  P        RAA 3-5
```